# Customizing L2 Cache Sharing between Cores

Tags: gem5

I am trying to create a multi-chip multi-processor design where the L2 Caches are private to each chip. For example I am trying to create the following configuration:

- 2 Chips each containing 2 CPU Cores
- Each Chip has 2 CPU Cores(each having its own L1 Cache) and a single L2 Cache shared between the two CPUs
- Finally I will have the Main Memory shared between the 2 Chips

I am using the **MOESI_CMP_directory** protocol to generate the design. And I am using garnet2.0 to create the topology. But what I have understood is that all of the 4 CPUs share the two L2-Caches. But I want the L2-Cache be private to each Chip. Is there any way to do that in gem5?

Additional Info:

I checked the memory addresseses and accessed Caches through RubyNetwork to confirm that L1-Cache0 accesses L2-Cache0 as well as L2-Cache1. It seems the protocol is working correctly because L2 Cache being the last level cache is being shared. But I was wondering if I could make some customization so that L1-Cache0/1 requests only go to L2-Cache0 and not L2-Cache1.

Answer (score 0):

I think I know how to resolve this. There are two files which will need modification for this:

1. **src/mem/ruby/protocol/MESI_Two_Level-L1Cache.sm** - In this file the Coherent Messages from L1Cache are sent through "actions". The function which controls the mapping, as to which L2Cache Node receives the coherent request, is "mapAddressToRange". This function is passed certain parameters in the .sm file and can be modified.
2. **src/mem/ruby/slicc_interface/RubySlicc_ComponentMapping.hh** - This file contains the implementation of the functions "mapAddressToRange" and we can make modifications here as per our requirement.